# C# Newtonsoft.JSON Inner object mapping

Tags: c#, json.net

I lately ran into a problem that my json format was just 1 layer but for reuse of my models i would like to format them as in the example given below.

I could of course dump the json in the constructor and format it myself only i would love to keep my models a bit more abstract.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;  
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""Name"" : ""Blaa"",
            ""Age"" : 1,
            ""EyeColor"": ""Blue""
        }";

        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
        Person person = jsonObj.ToObject<Person>();

        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Eyes.Color);
    }
}

class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Eyes Eyes{ get; set; }
}

class Eyes
{
    [JsonProperty("EyeColor")]
    public string Color{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be uesful if you want to separate your data transfer objects from your domain model.

While it is possible to solve this in the DTO alone, the customization it requires doesn't allow for easy reuse nor for generating DTOs from example JSON.

You'd rather keep the DTO matching the JSON:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string EyeColor { get; set; }
}
```

Then map it into a domain model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Eyes Eyes { get; set; }

    // Empty ctor for various reasons
    public Person() { } 

    public Person(PersonDto dto)
        : this()
    {
        Name = dto.Name;
        Age = dto.Age;
        Eyes = new Eyes
        {
            Color = dto.EyeColor
        };
    }
}

public class Eyes
{
    public string Color{ get; set; }
}
```

The mapping could also be done using AutoMapper, for example.

Alternatively you could solve it through a property which is ignored, but returns or hydrates the Eyes instance:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Eyes Eyes { get; set; }

    public string EyeColor 
    {
        get { return Eyes.Color; }
        set { Eyes.Color =  value; }
    }

    public Person()
    {
        this.Eyes = new Eyes();
    }
}
```

Note I omitted the JsonProperty attributes, which aren't required if the property names match the JSON fields' names.

Comment: I see i should make up my mind about using DTO or Domain Model. 
Well thx for your time.